# The output of netstat -an show several lines twice

Tags: linux, netstat

Why the output of "netstat -an"  shows several lines twice (48035 and 48036)?

```
netstan -an

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48120           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48121           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp   213504      0 0.0.0.0:48123           0.0.0.0:* 
udp        0 0 0.0.0.0:48035                0.0.0.0:*
udp        0 0 0.0.0.0:48036                0.0.0.0:*
udp        0 0 0.0.0.0:48035                0.0.0.0:*
udp        0 0 0.0.0.0:48036                0.0.0.0:*
```

Comment: try printing more information ... use `-p` switch perhaps

Comment: I second @jsotola 's suggestion.  It's possible that there are multiple processes bound to that port.